# delete Terminal Shortcut alias

Tags: terminal, command

Terminal command to make shortcut:

```
alias yourCommand="YourTerminalCommand"
```

And i accidentally made new command with "yourCommand" so I want to delete it but how?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
_unalias [name of alias]_
```

Don't use 
     unalias -a

It will delete all your alias.

Comment: I use unalias [name of alias] and removes just the named alias:  Check this : http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uunalias.htm

Comment: Keep in mind that alias created on teminal are temporal, if you want to permanent append an alias to your terminal you mus edit your bashrc if using bash, or zsh config file.